# Which is the best way to "look up" between 2 select boxes in django form

Tags: jquery, python, django, django-forms, lookup

I have a form with a selectbox called "category". It is filtered by another list of products. In few words, when selecting a product, the category select box is redrawn and shows just the categories associated to that product. I was trying to do that with javascript (jquery), using an ajax function and retrieving the list.

However, my problem is how to define that field (category) in the form.

```
category = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=IssueCategory.objects.all().order_by('name'), empty_label=EMPTY_CATEGORY_LABEL, required=False)
```

or

```
category = forms.ChoiceField(choices=(), required=False)
```

In the first example, I'm retrieving all the categories from all the products, which seems not pretty good since that list might be very big.

In the second example, I'm using just a empty ChoiceField. It looks the best way to do it but it is disconnected with the model and I need to some tricks in the clean_category to convert it to a Django object.

Opinions, suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure, that the first list is too big to load it (just load it not show it)? Because if not a simple solution can be the combination of the above - have the first (hidden) choicefield list all categories and have the second one show the relevant ones. The second one you fill up with jquery - this will not use Ajax so it is very fast once loaded. And accessing saving the elements is then easy because they will already have the proper ids.

Comment: I've used such method (http://www.abidibo.net/blog/2013/08/27/django-chained-selects-mootools/) to solve chained selects using mootools, it would be easy enough to convert the js code to jquery, but it loads all items (in your case all categories)

Answer (score 0):

How about using `IssueCategory.objects.none()`? And do something like this in your init:

```
def __init__(self, data=None, *args, **kwargs):
    super(YourForm, self).__init__(data, *args, **kwargs)
    if data:
        self.fields["category"].queryset = \ 
                IssueCategory.objects.filter(product=data["product"])
```